# Javax Validation With H2

Tags: java, spring, h2

I have this test

```
@Test
public void mustPostAccountCreationExceptionWithMoreThanTwoDigitsAfterComma(){
    thrown.expect(ConstraintViolationException.class);

    account.setSaldo(new BigDecimal("12.000"));
    accountRepository.save(account);
}
```

And this validation for the field `saldo`:

```
@Digits(fraction = 2, integer = 9)
private BigDecimal saldo;
```

But with H2 not works and Postgresql works

Answer (score 0):

To add in pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
<artifactId>h2</artifactId>
<version>1.4.196</version>
<scope>test</scope>
```

and delete config-beans for Postgresql
or post me your project,I can to help you

Comment: I believe that I don't have config-beans on my project, My project is on github https://github.com/LuizdosReis/controleOrcamento